# linux: How to determine the best filesystem format?

Tags: linux, filesystems

About a year ago I changed from running Windows as dual boot to very rarely running Windows as a VM. As a result most of my partitions are in ntfs ( so I had access on both sides of the boot ). I have decided to reformat all these partitions to ...

Looking for the best first class filesystem format,

I am using a desktop with 1T-2T storage.

So how do I determine which one best serves my needs?

Comment: Do you mean 1T-2T of storage, I hope?

Comment: @ATC My mistake.

Comment: <twitch/> "T" is not a unit of information. It should be "TB" or "TiB".

Comment: I remember the old days when the B/b letter wasn't used, i.e. we'd say 64K RAM instead of 64KiB RAM.

Answer (score 10):

Best file system is subjective. Since you haven't specified your needs I'd suggest to use `EXT4`. It has got better speed and support files with sizes up to 16TB.

Comment: Have a look at this link too : (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165/what-is-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-ext4-and-reiserfs-and-jfs-and-xfs/336#336)

Comment: Clearly it's not subjective. It's dependent on the application obviously, but it's not like a colour or something. For example, for me, data integrity is important, so I put all my disks in a ZPS pool. Ext4 wouldn't be good enough. Admittedly, on linux your choices are somewhat reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Look what other filesystem(s) you are using ATM.

Try to keep it simple - most probably you are running ext3/4, just stick with it.